# Can I access the result string calling the completion in my function? - swift

Tags: swift

I'd just like to know if its possible to access the string with which I am completing a certain function after the latter happens. For example:

```
func getVideos(pID: String, completion: (result:String)->()) {
completion(result: "done")
}

Networking().getVideos(selectedID) { (result: String) -> () in
//ID LIKE TO ACCESS THE "done" STRING HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for asking such an easy question. The answer was in my face.

The printing the 'result' parameter after completion will print whatever string (in this case "done") that I declare in the definition.